# Python mapped object becoming empty after being reduced

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
A = map(lambda x: x * 2, [1, 2])
z = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, A)

print(z, list(A))
# outputs: 6 []
```

It's so confused that the canonical `map reduce` FP operation leads to the destructive end. What has happened beneath the surface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` returns an iterator. Your `reduce` fully consumes that iterator, so there is nothing left afterwards. If you turn `A` into a list before the `reduce`, it works as expected:

```
A = list(map(lambda x: x * 2, [1, 2]))
z = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, A)
print(z,A)   #prints 6 [2, 4]
```

Comment: terminology/typing nitpick: `map` does *not* return a generator. It returns an iterator.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In programming, terminology is important and isn't just a nitpick. Thanks.